# Android debugging problems

Tags: android, debugging

I am very new to Android and Eclipse. I find very difficult to fix up the errors in Eclipse. Android emulator keeps crashing, even for few lines of codes. Is there any tutorial or video tutorial available, that can help me to spot errors on looking at the error log.

Comment: Does the emulator crash or the app in the emulator? The docs have some good starter articles on first apps

Comment: can u tell me in which case there is crash?? give me more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic tutorial that will get you familiar with Android Debugging and Logcat : [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) . Also you can set breakpoints and debug as you would for any other Eclipse project. The logging of errors, its different tough, using `Logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open DDMS perspective and LogCat window to view logs and can see what is the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

When it crashes, check the [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html). It contains the stack trace with the exception, and is often enough to see what went wrong and fix it. It can be browsed directly in Eclipse (don't know exactly how, I'm using IntelliJ).

Also, you can use normal debugging on your Android project, exactly the same way you would on a Java (non-Android) project.